# In cricket, How pitch can decide match result?

Tags: cricket

In cricket, how can the pitch decide the match's result?  We all know match result depends on the player's performance.

Answer (score 2):

The condition of the pitch directly effects the ease of playing the game.  The condition of the pitch effects how easy it is for the batsmen to play shots with confidence, how much the ball will move either through seam or spin and how quickly the ball will travel off the bat.

Generally a good pitch should provide assistance to all, bounce and pace for bowlers and batsmen and then wear over the course of the match bringing the spinners into the match.

In multi day cricket if a pitch is too good it will tend to lead to a high scoring draw which is boring.

Pitch condition as well as being effected by wear is effected by the weather, so what is a nice hard dry pitch could become a lot less pleasant to bat on after rain and it sweating under covers.

Therefore the pitch condition is an important factor in deciding what to do after the toss.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a test match where the pitch deteriorates significantly over the course of the match, so that by the 4th or 5th day it has very inconsistent bounce and pace and therefore batting is *much* harder than it was on the earlier days. At that point, if you've got two reasonably matched teams, the team batting last is almost certainly going to lose.

Obviously, if you put a pub team against the South African test team, the South Africa test team is still going to win no matter when they bat, but it's generally considered a bad thing if the pitch has a *significant* input on the result.